# How can I maximize my chances of a professor of another university accepting to be my undergraduate research advisor?

Tags: advisor, undergraduate, research-undergraduate, supervision, communication

Next year I'm going to college and would like to do undergraduate research in the second semester under the supervision of a certain professor, who I'll call Prof. M.

There are three points against me and three in my favor. They are the following

1. Prof. M. works at another university, which is about 100 miles away from the one I'm going to. If he does accept to advise me, my plan is to travel to his university every week or every other week.
2. I am worse than terrible when it comes to social aspects: I talk too fast, lack common sense, and I feel horribly nervous when talking to other people (specially people I don't know), often leading to awkward behavior for not knowing how to act.
3. Prof. M. is a (local) bigshot. (I'm assuming he might be more selective because of this)
4. I have self-studied math and physics more or less to have approximately the technical understanding a second year graduate student would have. Of course, while I know about e.g. locally ringed spaces or bosonic string theory (or insert buzzword here), I lack most of the skills and experience a real graduate student would have, such as being able to critically read research papers or having research experience. Also, this is a self-assessment, thus possibly a faulty one;
5. The professor is welcoming and has a nice personality (I got this information from a friend that has a friend who was a phd student in the same university as Prof. M. and who talked to him personally);
6. He has supervised* undergraduate students in the past (about five years ago);

So,

1. should I talk to Prof. M. personally or by email?
2. should I mention a paper he wrote that I find particularly
   interesting and ask if he would accept advising me to do similar
   research?

In short, **what is the best path to be taken here?**

---

*Though all undergraduate students are from his university. See Professor Eldredge's comment below.

Comment: I have refeered to him/her by him/her to try to make this situation more anonymous

Comment: Does Prof Bigshot have a history of supervising undergraduates *from your university*?  In many fields, typically including math and probably physics, supervising undergraduate research is a net drain on the professor's time, resulting in lower overall research productivity.  A professor has certain incentives to do this for their university's own students (to some extent it's part of their job), but unless some sort of special arrangement exists, they probably have no incentives to do it for someone from another university.

Comment: @NateEldredge Dear Professor Eldredge,

Thank you for the reply (all the more during Christmas (eve)).

(S)he has supervised 8 undergraduates, all from his/her university. 1 out of 30 phds+masters+post-docs (s)he has supervised did her phd at my university, though.

Best wishes.

Comment: @DanRomik Dear Professor Romik,

Thank you for replying (all the more during Christmas (eve)). I'm flattered to know you think so; thank you very much!

Would it be better to try speak in person or by email? Also, I'll be sure to prepare for the quizzing, a small mini-qual, if you will.

Again, thank you for your kindness.

Best wishes.

Comment: @UndergradResearch I have no idea.

Comment: @DanRomik Dear Professor Romik,
Thank you for your reply.
Best wishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reasons completely unrelated to your own skills and background, I think your chances  here are slim. The professor has little external incentive to take you on and doing so will complicate his/her already too busy academic life. There might even be rules forbidding it, though the chance of that is small.

But, you ask how you can maximize your chances, so I'll give some hints.

This is the sort of thing you want to do in person, not by mail/email. You certainly won't get a positive answer via an email exchange. You might get an invitation to visit, but that puts you face-to-face in any case.

This is the sort of thing you want to do in conjunction with an advocate/intermediary. If you were already established in "your" college, one of your professors would be good for doing that. Especially since the prof once studied there. But if you have a current teacher who knows this person (or is known) they might be willing to intervene on your behalf, perhaps even accompanying you on a visit to the other university.

I'm not sure that waiting until you are established at university is a good thing or not. You won't have a lot of time to become recognized before you need to make the contact. But it would give you the potential for finding an intermediary.

You will need to convince the prof that you have unique skills and that it would be a missed opportunity not to work with you. That is a pretty steep climb. It would help if some of your research interests align. So you need to demonstrate that you know something of the research of the prof and how you might fit in.

But I also have a small wonder about why you chose the university you did, rather than the other one. You would maximize your chance by going there instead.

Don't worry about being/seeming awkward. Lots of people in academia are likewise.

Comment: Dear Professor Buffy,
Thank you for your reply. (Specially during Christmas!)
From here on I will refer to the professor at the other university as Prof. M.
Is the following a good approach?
1. Ask a welcoming professor of my university for advice
2. Inquire at some point of the conversation about having an advocate/intermediary
3. Ask if (s)he either knows Prof. M. or knows some other professor at my university who knows Prof. M.
Or perhaps should I just ask to the point (but cordially) if (s)he knows a professor who is acquainted with Prof. M. as to save his/her time?
Thank you...

Comment: ...for your advice and for the time you put at answering.
Best wishes.
P. S. A side question: is it wrong or unnatural to refer to the university one studies at as “my college” or “my university”? Or did you use quotes since I don't study there yet? Sorry to bother you with this (somewhat unrelated) question. (Note: I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: P.P.S. Thank you very much for the last piece of advice. Being awkward worries me a lot when I think about building relationships with professors, students, or (future) collaborators. It is very reassuring to know that I shouldn't worry about this.

Comment: I do not agree with the first paragraph of this response. I usually do not take on random students from other universities - however, if a student comes with clear interest in a topic close to my specialty, good background preparation and ideally a concrete idea (even if it is not the final direction of the research), I will always at least give it consideration to find a way of making a supervision feasible. Don't worry about awkwardness - if the prof is capable and has a pleasant personality, they will be interested in your science, not your nervousness.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Dear Captain Emacs,
Thank you for your reply. (Specially during Christmas (or during the Holiday season, depending on your time zone))
I'll keep in mind to have a concrete idea for research when I do meet Prof. M. next year. Could you elaborate on how concrete the idea should be?
Thank you for reassuring me about my awkwardness.
Best wishes.

Comment: @UndergradResearch Basically, the point should be - why should they work with you? But it should also be interesting for you...

Comment: Dear @CaptainEmacs,

Prof. M. lists his main research interests in his homepage, one of which—let's call it X—particularly interests me (but I'm also interested in other topics he pursues)

Would it suffice to prepare for doing research on X (say by trying to understand some papers he wrote on X) and then asking if he would advise me in doing (original) research on X? (So that I could be useful to him in advancing his research (even if only a bit))

As always, thank you for your patience.

Best wishes.

Comment: @UndergradResearch Why do you want to work with him? That's the main question you have to ask. If that reason does not work for him, he is not the right person for you, anyway...

Comment: Dear @CaptainEmacs,

I want to work with him because
1. he is a great mathematician
2. he has a pleasant personality
3. works in an area which interests me very much. In fact, I'm not very interested in the research areas of either the professors of "my" university, or of the professors from a really close university in "my" city.

While searching for potential advisors sometime ago, I decided that I wanted to work with him because of (3), then I learned about (1), and finally (2).

If I can indeed work with him, compared to working with other professors, I believe that I might...

Comment: ...
1. be able to do better work
2. possibly become a better scientist (than if working with other professors)

On his side, to also be able to "repay" him for advising me, I would strive to advance his research.

I apologize for the long reply. While I'm not sure if these reasons are right, I admire him a lot, and somehow have a "gut feeling" that he is probably the right advisor. If possible, could you give me an example of a valid reason? (specially one that would work for both an advisor and an advisee)

Thank you for your attention and time.

Best wishes.

Comment: The question was not really mine - this question is what you need to ask yourself and essentially answer in your contact mail. Keep in mind that a too effusive letter may have the opposite of the desired effect. It will cause him to worry about the fact that rejecting you may make you more insistent or may frustrate you too much. Keep it focused - your key reason to work with him is (3). The other reasons are not relevant for his decision-making. It is clear that a student will want to improve themselves - but what does the student bring to the table? That is what your prof will want to know.

Comment: Dear @CaptainEmacs,
I will be sure to keep these in mind, do my best at trying to understand the situation from his side, think deeply about it, and formulate an appropriate mail/conversation. Thank you very much!
Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution I don't think anyone has mentioned is to have an official supervisor at your own institution, and a collaboration with Prof M at '100 mile University'. A more limited scope of direct supervision (say 1/month contact with more frequent meetings with your local super to handle the day-to-day stuff) might seem like less of an additional burden if they are hesitant to add you to their workload. You would then have access to both their specialist knowledge and a local super for the more general stuff and university admin side of things.

Comment: Dear @The_Tams,

Thanks for the reply (specially during the Holiday season).

However, if possible, I would like to avoid following this plan for the following reason. There are no professors in "my university" closeto the area of Prof. M. (The closest being something like geometric topology and algebraic geometry, or data analysis and neural networks) I believe this clash of research interests _might_, in the long term, create a bad relationship between me, my local advisor, and Prof. M.

I'm not sure if this would present a problem, so please tell me if you think otherwise...

Comment: ...My reluctance notwithstanding, thank you for your answer.

Best wishes.

Comment: Whether or not something like that would work is in part up to their personailties. I have worked with wonderful profs whose egos wouldn't find this arrangement a problem. Perhaps consider it a Plan C or such-like to have in your back pocket when you speak to Prof. M.

Comment: Dear @The_Tams,
From what I heard about Prof. M.'s personality, I think he wouldn't mind this arrangement. I'll be sure to know a pleasant prof (with reasonable ego) working in the university I'm going to study at to have Plan C available. Thank you!
Best wishes.